# Why does DependencyProperty override the normal property binding behavior?

Tags: wpf, binding

I occasionally ran into an issue. here is a simple example:

Xaml Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFProperties.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="root">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ElementName=root}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    //public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    //    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set 
        {
            if (this._text == value) return;
            _text = value;

            this.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do Someting
    }
}
```

Method DoSomething() can be invoked, when typing on the textbox. but, once i uncomment the dependency property "Text", it is never be called.

**Note:** I know the basic usage of dependency property.

Comment: check this http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html. maybe then you know something about dependency properties

Answer (score 2):

you need to create UIPropertyMetaData with callback (PropertyChangedCallback propertyChangedCallback) which should be static method inside which you should call update property on passed DependancyObject

example is explained here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well AFAIK there is no normal property declaration happening here since when a DP is declared it's `static` which gets initialized right at the very start before even normal objects are created and it has precedence.

Hence the property in the class is just treated as a normal DP helper property instead of what looks like a new class member property. Thus the binding internals just uses the internal `SetValue(...)` or `GetValue(...)` directly bypassing your over-ride which is normal behavior for a DP.

When no DP is declared then this becomes a normal property of the class and inturn we see your  `DoSomething()` called.

Again even with the DP definition not commented if we call `Text = "Anything"` in the MainWindow's constructor we can see `DoDomething()` invoked since that's the way DP's work where your local helper is called. Just binding's use the base definition's